# I can not access Journal Items on Odoo 16

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-16

RPC_ERROR

Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 85, in lookup

r = d[key]

File "<decorator-gen-6>", line 2, in **getitem**

File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/tools/func.py", line 87, in locked

return func(inst, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/tools/lru.py", line 34, in **getitem**

a = self.d[obj]

KeyError: ('account.move.line', <function Model._get_view_cache at 0x7f79df612cb0>, (1029, 'tree', None, 'en_US', None))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1584, in _serve_db

return service_model.retrying(self._serve_ir_http, self.env)

File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 133, in retrying

result = func()

File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1611, in _serve_ir_http

response = self.dispatcher.dispatch(rule.endpoint, args)

File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1815, in dispatch

result = self.request.registry['ir.http']._dispatch(endpoint)

File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/addons/website/models/ir_http.py", line 237, in _dispatch

response = super()._dispatch(endpoint)

File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 154, in _dispatch

result = endpoint(**request.params)

File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 697, in route_wrapper

result = endpoint(self, *args, **params_ok)

File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/addons/web/controllers/dataset.py", line 42, in call_kw

return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)

File "/home/odoo/src/user/standard-modules/printnode_base/controllers/main.py", line 79, in _call_kw

result = super(DataSetProxy, self)._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)

File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/addons/web/controllers/dataset.py", line 33, in _call_kw

return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)

File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 457, in call_kw

result = _call_kw_model(method, model, args, kwargs)

File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 430, in _call_kw_model

result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 2511, in get_views

result['views'] = {

File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 2512, in <dictcomp>

v_type: self.get_view(

File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 2696, in get_view

result = dict(self._get_view_cache(view_id, view_type, **options))

File "<decorator-gen-48>", line 2, in _get_view_cache

File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 90, in lookup

value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 2659, in _get_view_cache

arch, models = view.postprocess_and_fields(arch, model=self._name, **options)

File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 1036, in postprocess_and_fields

name_manager = self._postprocess_view(node, model or self.model, **options)

File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 1176, in _postprocess_view

postprocessor(node, name_manager, node_info)

File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 1321, in _postprocess_tag_groupby

self._postprocess_view(node, field.comodel_name, editable=False, parent_name_manager=name_manager)

File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 1176, in _postprocess_view

postprocessor(node, name_manager, node_info)

File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 1321, in _postprocess_tag_groupby

self._postprocess_view(node, field.comodel_name, editable=False, parent_name_manager=name_manager)

File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 1176, in _postprocess_view

postprocessor(node, name_manage

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).